# Left/right shift for inserting into an ordered vector

Tags: java, vector, data-structures, ordereddictionary

For a programming assignment, we were asked to create an ordered vector class. My question is on my "leftShift" function.

My first code, which compiled fine, but would crash with an index out of bounds exception when ran with a tester file.

```
**private E LeftShift(int index){
        E Temp = arrayFirst[index];
        for (int x = index ; x<= size -1 ; x++){
            arrayFirst[x] = arrayFirst[x+1];
        } 
        return Temp;**
```

It gave me a good amount of headache, but after some trial and error I simply removed an `=` to get it to function properly.

```
**private E leftShift(int index){
        E Temp = arrayFirst[index];
        for (int x = index ; x < size -1 ; x++){
            arrayFirst[x] = arrayFirst[x+1];
        }
        return Temp;**
```

While it does work, I would like to have a better understanding as to why my first code would crash and what makes the second work without error. Any explanation is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is it the desired result that the last two elements of the vector be the same after `leftShift` is called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first block of code, `x` will iterate until `x <= size - 1` is false (until `x > size - 1`).

Thus on the final iteration `x = size - 1`. Within the loop, on the final iteration you access `arrayFirst[x+1]`, which is `arrayFirst[(size - 1) + 1] = arrayFirst[size]`.

This is out of bounds. This error doesn't occur in the second code block because you stop when `x == size - 1`, so this bad iteration doesn't occur.